# How do I select information from ManyToMany Table in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities mapped Board and Tag by @ManyToMany to a join table board_tag_table.

How would I return the top 5 most common tag_id in the board_tag_table?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vxxt.png)

```
public class Board {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "board_tag_table",
    joinColumns = {
            //primary key of Board
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
            //primary key of Tag
            @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "tag_id")
    })
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer tag_id;

    private String tagname;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Board> boards = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Unable to find how to query within a many to many table

Answer (score 0):

you can pass through foreach and write your query in Tag repository, but I think you can't write query, because they are have list from two sides

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a native query instead.

If you want to use the JPA, you can add a field (Eg. `usedCount`) in the Tag entity and follow the instructions here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result.

The query should look like this:

`List<Tag> findByUsedCount(Sort sort, Pageable pageable);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't look at it as trying to access the board_tag_table, and instead look at how you would do this with the java entities themselves. This would be just selecting the 5 top Tags based on the number of boards they have. "select t.tag_id, count(b) as boardCount from Tag t join t.boards b group by t.tag_id order by boardCount", then use maxResults to limit the returned values to 5

Comment: I'm sorry but where would I add this line and how would I call it? In the TagRepository maybe with @Query annotation?